# iterating through Map object using angular2 ngFor

Tags: java, angular, hashmap, ngfor

I have a hashed map object that the key is a string representing a class number and the value for each key is an Arraylist of Student object so in general the object that I want to iterate through is of type:
`Map<String,Arraylist<Student>>`
I want to display a tree like structure of the object values, I tried to use :

`<div *ngFor="let key of MyObject">{{key}} </div>` 
But this shows only the class number but it does not show the students names in each class. does anyone know how to iterate through each key and each object inside that key?

Comment: JavaScript doesn't use Java objects. Post the structure of the JavaScript object/array that you want to iterate on.

Comment: In F12 it looks like this: MyObject >"Classe123">[{Name:"Student1",Marks:20},{Name:"Student2",Marks:60}] and then there is another class under "Classe123" > "Classe998">[{Name:"Student3",Marks:70},{Name:"Student4",Marks:10}]

Comment: Execute `console.log(JSON.stringify(myObject))`, and post the result.Post it in your question, not in a comment.

Comment: Make use of pipes it will solve your issue

Answer (score 1):

You should create another *ngFor to iterate through the arrayList

```
<div *ngFor="let key of MyObject"> Class {{key}}
  Students:
  <div *ngFor="let student of MyObject.get(key)">
    {{student.name}}
  </div> 
</div>
```

this way it should display each class and each student in that class.